# Invalid video decoder config in MediaSource

Tags: media-source

I'm using MSE to play fragmented MP4 streams (H264 video) in browser(s).

The concept is working, there is a `MediaSource` and `SourceBuffer`, and I'm pushing data to SourceBuffer, and MediaSource is being displayed on the HTML page correctly.

**However I've now found a stream which my configuration simply can't play.**

I'd like to emphasize, that my MSE configuration is good and working for most of the streams - for all the streams I've tried until now. So I'd just skip the details of implementation for sake of simplicity.

There is an error message with a lot of details:

`CHUNK_DEMUXER_ERROR_APPEND_FAILED: Invalid video decoder config: codec: h264, profile: h264 baseline, level: not available, alpha_mode: is_opaque, coded size: [0,0], visible rect: [0,0,0,0], natural size: [0,0], has extra data: false, encryption scheme: Unencrypted, rotation: 0°, flipped: 0, color space: {primaries:BT709, transfer:BT709, matrix:BT709, range:LIMITED}`

It seems the video itself doesn't have the correct size information.

So the obvious question: **(How) is it possible to configure the MediaSource's video decoder to update the stream's size (width and height) parameters?**

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with the video bitstream of that particular piece of content. More specifically, in the decoder initialization config which usually is contained in *special* NAL units (SPS and PPS) of the initialization segment(s).

You probably won't be able to work around that. If you were to fix it you'd most likely have to re-write those NAL units in the bitstream which is not typically something to do on the client side. It's a content authoring issue.

Also, you might want to cross-validate with https://conformance.dashif.org/ or the [dash.js reference player](https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/).